# Run window media player or VLC using VB script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I want to run window media player using .vbs file
currently i'am running applications like this

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objWord = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
```

but not get any way to run window media player and also want to play a sample file in media player

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VBScript

```
Set wmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
wmp.openPlayer("D:\MP3\Adiemus.mp3")
```

In PowerShell:

```
$wmp = New-Object -ComObject WMPlayer.OCX
$wmp.openPlayer("D:\MP3\Adiemus.mp3")
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i stop ?

Comment: Try with $wmp.controls.stop()

Comment: but it doesn't close window media player

Answer (score 0):

The above code will help to run the exe file. After running the exe file is it possible to select the path of installation and select "yes" to start installation